# Why are the arrows in my Bootstrap Popovers incorrectly aligned to the popover content?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I've been having an issue where the arrows attached to bootstrap popovers are off to the bottom on some but not all of the popovers that appear on my page.  Here's what the issue looks like:
[image]

This was the case only for popovers attached to text that you have to scroll to.  So if you load the page and mouse over text with a popover that appears up front, there won't be an issue.  If you scroll down and mouse over text that you scrolled to, then the issue will appear.

What's causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason at one point I included in my css:

```
html{
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

Removing that fixed the problem.